# Inside a remote modal, a link to another URL to be opened in the same modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

You can open a modal inside a page that is a link to another page, and will also be opened using the same modal?

The "traditional" way is not possible, see: http://plnkr.co/llRUSYXKziaaV1WvXnrJ

Even wiping the data :

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to replace the modal content?

Comment: It is a possibility. I expected that already existed a native way, of the Bootstrap.

Comment: The problem is that the same link is now in a normal page, now is in a modal.